# Extracting a string format using lua

Tags: string, lua, lua-patterns

I have a string

```
(A file location) = "C:\User\Projects\54a2135.tif"
```

There are several tiff files in the location and I will need to pick them and move them to a different folder.

My difficulty is in getting only the `.tif` file . I tried `string.match`, `string.gsub`, `string.find` but unable to achieve that. Is there any advice on how I extract just the `.tif` file (In this case `54a2135.tif`) from that string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start with, `\` is the escape character, so it should be escaped in double/single quoted strings. (The other option is to use the long string `[[...]]`)

Then you can use pattern matching:

```
local path = "C:\\User\\Projects\\54a2135.tif"
print(path:match("[^\\]*$"))
```

The pattern `[^\\]*$` matches any non-backslash characters at the end of the string.

If you like to specify it's a `.tif` file, change the pattern to `[^\\]*%.tif$`

Comment: Thank you so much Yu Hao. It worked like a charm. I appreciate your help. Cant thank you enough...